# Why does my "string mingling" method return unexpected results?

Tags: c++, string, c++14, subscript

I'm trying to implement a simple "string mingling" method, which recursively mingles two strings of equal size (e.g. cat and dog becomes cdaotg -- first letter from string 1, first letter from string 2, and so on).

My method is as follows:

```
string mingleStrings(string s1, string s2, int index) {
    if (index >= s1.length()) {
        return "";
    } else {
        string mingled = "";
        mingled += s1[index] + s2[index];
        mingled += mingleStrings(s1,s2,++index);
        return mingled;
    }
}
```

When I use the subscript operator on my string (s1[index]), it returns the entire string up to that index. To get a specific character of the string at a certain index, I need to type s1[index,index]. This is new to me.

Comment: Could you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where `s1[index]` gives back a whole substring and where `s1[index,index]` fixes that? It definitely shouldn't happen and `index,index` just evaluates `index` twice and uses the second evaluation.

Comment: Couldn't it be neither?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is on this line:

```
mingled += s1[index] + s2[index];
```

What this does is adding *codes* of characters at `index`, and then appending the result of the addition to your string as a single character.

It should be two separate operations:

```
mingled += s1[index];
mingled += s2[index];
```

This way you append a single character to the string each time you call `+=`, producing the result that you expect.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/QquYLr)

Comment: Coud you please elaborate? One would think that the `+` operator between two strings (to the right of the `+=`) will concatenate them first and then concatenate to the string on the left side.

Comment: @AlejandroIván, The result of indexing a string is a character, not a string. Unfortunately, adding `char` silently adds numbers instead of being an error without a cast (C++ does it exactly like C does here).

Comment: @chris huh, good point. Haven't thought about it, it's been years since I worked with the string/char difference. Thanks.

Comment: This is unintuitive to me. I feel as though adding characters implies concatenation, based on how strings are sequences of characters. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: @Brandon C++ inherited this semantics from C, where `char` is an integral type that happens to be small. Other than that, it behaves like an integer: you can add, subtract, and even multiply and divide characters. One place where it is actually useful to subtract chars is determining the sequence number of a number or a digit: if you have `char c = 'F`;` and then you do `int pos = c - 'A'`, then `pos` would give you a zero-based index of the letter `F` in the alphabet.

Comment: @Brandon maybe using `originalString.substr(position, 1)` (which returns a `string`) instead of `originalString[position]` (which returns a `char`) could help. Notice that it's less efficient than accessing the `char` directly.